# How to open all files at once using VS Code as a Git difftool and mergetool?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-difftool

Currently, I have VS Code configured to be my `git difftool` and `git mergetool`

My `~\.gitconfig` file looks like this:

```
[user]
    email = myemail@gmail.com
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait $MERGED
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

However, when I run `git difftool`, it will ask me

```
Viewing (1/6): 'Repo\directory\someCode.cs'                                                                                                                 
Launch 'vscode' [Y/n]?
```

Is there a way to open all diffs at once? It is useful to be able to cycle between files without having to close them.

Comment: Would git difftool --dir-diff help? As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17739808/6309.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way I found is:

1. Adding an alias for the .bashrc file located in /home/.bashrc (Debian/Ubuntu distro).
2. At the end add the line 
   `alias difftool="git difftool -y"`
   and save it.
3. Reload the bash with the command 
   `source ~/.bashrc`
   from the terminal.
4. Try to run it again.

Comment: Hmm. I'm on Windows. I'll have to think about how to do the equivalent in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Check if VSCode 1.53 (Jan. 2021) can help:

> ### [Git: New command "Open All Changes"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/8cd1836d6b867d466bec3637e2da29c1a61859a9/release-notes/v1_53.md#source-control):
>
> A new Git command has been added to the Command Palette:
>
> ```
> Git: Open All Changes... - Opens all modified and untracked files.
> ```

That way, you can directly check changes from VSCode instead of calling VSCode from the command-line though  `git difftool` as [I suggested initially in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59903078/how-to-open-all-files-at-once-using-vs-code-as-a-git-difftool-and-mergetool/76244150#comment105940394_59903078) (`git difftool --dir-diff`).

Comment: Any chance you have an example of how to configure it? I'm not real well versed on manipulating git config files.

Comment: @KolobCanyon The idea behind that answer is to *not* manipulate git config files, but simply call this new command (in VSCode 1.53 not yet released)

Answer (score -1):

```
git difftool -d master..prod
```

This works better